# not able to add data to sqlite3 database, is it a database problem or did i make a mistake?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I am not able to add data to the database, below is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///friends.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Friends(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    date_created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<name %r>'& self.id 

@app.route('/friends', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def friends():
    if request.method == "POST":
        friend_name = request.form['name']
        new_friend = Friends(name=friend_name)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_friend)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/friends')
        except:
            return "friend could not be added"
    else:
        friends = Friends.query.order_by(Friends.date_created)
        return render_template("friends.html", title = title, friends = friends)
```

friends.html:

```
<form action="/friends" METHOD="POST">
    <input type="text" name= "name" placeholder="enter name">
    <input type="submit" value="Add name" class="btn btn-secondary">
</form>
{% for friend in friends %}
    <li>{{friend}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The first error i am getting is

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

When I delete `Self.id` , it works however the friend list is added to the database under `<name %r>` and not the name which was added in the form. I know that I did something wrong but I am not able to find it.

Comment: The first error is you're using `&` where you should be using `%`; change that repr to e.g. `return f'<name {self.id}>'` for brevity.

Comment: In `'<name %r>'& self.id` you meant `'<name %r>' % self.id`

Comment: @ForceBru thank you, fixed. now it shows <name1> <name2> etc.. furthermore the maximum value assigned to the name string is 10 but names with more than 10 characters are still added to the database and of course is shows <name5> etc..

Answer (score 0):

i should have added {{friend.name}} instead of {{friend}} .